# Question in proof of Hilbert Nullstellensatz

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory

I have a question in proof of Hilbert Nullstellensatz from my classnotes and I am not able to think about it.

Statement: If E is a field extension of K and E is K-algebra of finite type , then E|K is algebraic .

Proof: E|K is a field extension and $E= K[X_1,...,X_n]$ . To prove: E is algebraic over K. Put $Q_i =Qt(K[X_1,...,X_i])$ i=0,...,n.  $K= Q_0 \subseteq Q_1 \subseteq ... \subseteq ...Q_{i+1} \subseteq Q_n =E$. Let $m = Min ${r |$Q_{i+1}$ is finite over $Q_i$ }  where i=r,...,n-1. ie $Q_{i+1}$ is finite dim  $Q_i$ -vector space. ... (the proof continues) . (**I am not able to think why such m always exists**).

Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: Do you mean $r = \min \mathcal{M}, \; \mathcal{M} = \{ k \, | \, Q_{i+1} \; \text{is finite over} \; Q_i \; \text{for} \; i = k, k+1, \dots, n-1\}$? If so, it's enough to show that $\mathcal{M} \neq \emptyset$.

Comment: @HansEngler You are right.

Comment: This field version is pretty obvious: if $E/K$ is not algebraic, then there exists $x \in E$ which is not algebraic over $K$. It follows that $1, x, x^2, \dots$ are linearly independent over $K$, contradicting the assumption that $E/K$ has finite dimension.

Comment: @WhatsUp The assumption was that $E/K$ is  of finite type, not that It's finite dimensional.

Comment: @HansEngler Can you please answer my question if you have some time to spare?